# MS Access: Using a SQL UPDATE statement to update a table record using a String variable

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, sql-update, ms-access-2016

I'm trying to get an MS Access database to add the name of a file as it is imported (

> a String variable named "Name"

). The table is called "tbl_feed_import" and the column I need to update is "F26". I need to update each record in the table, so I have omitted the WHERE part of my update statement.

However, when I run my import function all I get is " & name & " in the table instead of the actual filename (and yes, I realize this will include the filepath for now).

Below is my code:

```vb
Public Sub Import_File()

DoCmd.RunSQL "Delete * from tbl_feed_import"

Dim feedfile, rec_count
Dim db As Database
Dim rs As Recordset
Set db = CurrentDb
Dim name As String

feedfile = FindfileXLS(CurrentProject.Path & "\Feed\")

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel5, "tbl_feed_import", feedfile, False, "Timecards data!A2:AC"

name = feedfile

'Test to see if the "name" variable can be passed to a text box
MsgBox name, vbOKOnly, "Imports Completed"

strSQL = "UPDATE tbl_feed_import" & "SET F26= '" & name & "' "

DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL

DoCmd.OpenQuery "qry_append_import_to_consolidated", acViewNormal

Exit_Route:
    Set db = Nothing
    Set rs = Nothing
    Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure the `UPDATE` query even runs? I see an obvious syntax error with no space before `SET`. Please make sure actual SQL query is posted.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a [reserved word](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-e33eb3a9-8baa-4335-9f57-da237c63eabe) when you declare the 'name` variable

**My recommendations:**

1. Replace `Dim name As String` with `Dim strName As String`
2. Then replace all references in your code from `'name` to `strName`
3. Finally fix your SQL string so there's a space before the SET
   command

`strSQL = "UPDATE tbl_feed_import SET F26= '" & name & "' "`

Comment: *name* used here is a VBA variable which has nothing to do with Access database reserved words.

Comment: @Parfait From the MS-Access page I linked - `You might also encounter errors if you use a reserved word to name a control, an object, or a variable. `